# Why can't I use this closure inside a Rc<dyn Fn()>?

Tags: generics, rust, closures

I have this struct:

```rust
pub struct ImmEval<Out> {
    closure: Rc<dyn Fn(&Self) -> Out>
}
impl<Out> From<Rc<dyn Fn(&Self) -> Out>> for ImmEval<Out> {
    /// Constructs the evaluator from the specified closure.
    fn from(cl: Rc<dyn Fn(&Self) -> Out>) -> Self {
        ImmEval {closure: cl}
    }
}
impl<Out> Evaluator for ImmEval<Out> {
    type Output = Out;
    /// Evaluates and returns the result.
    fn eval(&self) -> Self::Output {
        (*self.closure)(self)
    }
}
```

which is used in a test like this:

```rust
let counter = Cell::new(0);
{
    let eval = ImmEval::<i32>::from(Rc::from(|_: &ImmEval<i32>| {
        counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
        counter.get()
    }));

    eval.eval();
    eval.eval();
}
assert_eq!(counter.get(), 2);
```

The struct itself compiles but the test does not. Instead, it fails with the following `rustc` message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ImmEval<i32>: std::convert::From<std::rc::Rc<[closure@src\tests.rs:8:51: 11:10 counter:_]>>` is not satisfied
  --> src\tests.rs:8:41
   |
8  |           let eval = ImmEval::<i32>::from(Rc::from(|_: &ImmEval<i32>| {
   |  _________________________________________^
9  | |             counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
10 | |             counter.get()
11 | |         }));
   | |__________^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::rc::Rc<[closure@src\tests.rs:8:51: 11:10 counter:_]>>` is not implemented for `ImmEval<i32>`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <ImmEval<Out> as std::convert::From<std::rc::Rc<(dyn for<'r> std::ops::Fn(&'r ImmEval<Out>) -> Out + 'static)>>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Surely this means that my closure isn't a valid `Fn(&ImmEval<i32>) -> i32`, but why?

[Here's the playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=714c33be9c270fc96fa3508732968785).

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] please? A playground link to a code that shows the error is a must.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow in Rust. There are too many self-references and HRTBs. You should design all of this differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution than creating a closure separately (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60209565/7616532), though I still appreciate the great explanation of the problem) is not using the `From` trait at all:

```rust
impl<'l, Out> ImmEval<'l, Out> {
    pub fn new<Cl>(closure: Cl) -> Self
    where Cl: (Fn(&ImmEval<Out>) -> Out) + 'l {
        let rcl: Rc<dyn Fn(&ImmEval<Out>) -> Out> = Rc::from(closure);
        ImmEval {closure: rcl}
    }
}
```

I replaced the `From` constructor with a generic `new` (and also added some lifetime specifiers to make sure that the closure lives long enough), which takes the closure itself (without the reference counter) and puts it into one in the same way that the first answer that I mentioned does. By then cloning the evaluator struct or adding a method `get_closure`, the reference-counted closure can be extracted and reused. Moreover, if the `From` trait is preserved, then the `get_closure` result would be usable in the same way as the first answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The type inference cannot be done in this situation. If you write the type you want, it works:

```
let f: Rc<dyn Fn(&ImmEval<i32>) -> i32> = Rc::new(|_: &ImmEval<i32>| {
    counter.set(counter.get() + 1);
    counter.get()
});
let eval = ImmEval::<i32>::from(f);
```

But that does not solve your other lifetime issues.

Comment: That's sad. What does the compiler need to infer the type though?

Comment: @VladislavToncharov That's the closest I could do: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=237b62ab24af8fd933339dd4eed7267c

Comment: @Vladislav How could the compiler know that you want to coerce `Rc<[closure]>` to `Rc<dyn Fn>` and then use `From<Rc<dyn Fn>>`? You didn't specify `dyn Fn` in either step. The compiler has no way of knowing *a priori* that you want to go through `dyn Fn` unless you give it a hint. The compiler must *deduce* types, it won't *guess* them.